# CakePHP problems with Yahoo, Hotmail and YopMail referals

Tags: email, session, cakephp, gmail, yahoo

Here's one of the most strangest problems i've ever seen in my life as developer:

I have a website running CakePHP (lastest version, always) and when I send an email to someone (using Yahoo, Hotmail or YopMail), let's say a "remember my password" message, the CakePHP don't work properly.

What should happend: user acess the website using the link sent via email, internal process (generating the new password and sending it via email to the user), redirect the user to the homepage with a message "Your new password was sent by email".

The problem is that when the user clicks the link he's redirected to the homepage without any session variables... And there's no generated email!

But if I send the SAME link to someone using gMail it works like a charm.

Do you have any clue about where I should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was some problem with the security level... I lowered it to "low" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in GMAIL, but not in YAHOO, then it sounds like yahoo is filtering your message. It's possible your wording triggers their spam or exploit filter. Just as a test, try sending the same link as an image link instead of using text. see if that works for yahoo.

Comment: But the email's not flagged as SPAM and I can click the text link